# PROBLEMA java.lang.NullPointerException Tentativo error al capturar datos de input, generar actualización o creación de Evento

Tags: java, primefaces, crud, glassfish

Tengo esta excepción en el momento en el que deseo actualizar o crear mi evento, para mi sistema, estoy usando GlassFish 5.1.0, jdk 1.8, mySQL 8.0.31.
Mi Clase evento se encuentra mapeada con la entidad que tengo en mi base de datos.
Dejo aquí las líneas de código que tengo.
Tentativamente siento que que el error se encuentra al capturar los nuevos datos al actualizar o al registrar el evento por medio del input, hay que tomar en cuenta que la cantidadBoletos es int y el precioTicket es float
Debo aclarar que me corre el codigo, sin embargo al momento de enlistar todo bien, al momento de actualizar o crear un nuevo evento me lanza este error en el GlassFish y no veo cambio en la interfaz.

**Clase EventoDaoImp**

```
    package com.sjgarciav.datos;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import com.sjgarciav.domain.Evento;

    @Stateless 
    public class EventoDaoImpl implements EventoDao{
    
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="SgaPU")
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Evento> findAllEventos() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Evento.findAll").getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Evento findEventoById(Evento evento) {
        return em.find(Evento.class, evento.getIdEvento());
    }

    @Override
    public Evento findEventoByGenero(Evento evento) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("from Evento e where e.genero =: genero");
        query.setParameter("genero", evento.getGenero());
        return (Evento) query.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertEvento(Evento evento) {
        em.persist(evento);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateEvento(Evento evento) {
        em.merge(evento);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEvento(Evento evento) {
        em.remove(em.merge(evento));
    }  
    }
```

**EventoServiceImp**

```
    package com.sjgarciav.servicio;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import com.sjgarciav.datos.EventoDao;
    import com.sjgarciav.domain.Evento;

    @Stateless
    public class EventoServiceImpl implements EventoServiceRemote, EventoService {

    @Inject
    private EventoDao eventoDao;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext contexto;

    @Override
    public List<Evento> listarEventos() {
        return eventoDao.findAllEventos();
    }

    @Override
    public Evento encontrarEventoPorId(Evento evento) {
        return eventoDao.findEventoById(evento);
    }

    @Override
    public Evento encontrarEventoPorGenero(Evento evento) {
        return eventoDao.findEventoByGenero(evento);
    }

    @Override
    public void registrarEvento(Evento evento) {
        eventoDao.insertEvento(evento);
    }

    @Override
    public void modificarEvento(Evento evento) {
        try {
            eventoDao.updateEvento(evento);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            contexto.setRollbackOnly();
            t.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void eliminarEvento(Evento evento) {
        eventoDao.deleteEvento(evento);
    }
    }
```

**EventoBean**

```
    package com.sjgarciav.web;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import javax.inject.Named;
    import com.sjgarciav.domain.Evento;
    import com.sjgarciav.servicio.EventoService;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;
    import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

    @Named("eventoBean")
    @RequestScoped
    public class EventoBean {
    
    Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();
    
    @Inject
    private EventoService eventoService;

    private Evento eventoSeleccionado;
    
      
    
    List<Evento> eventos;
    
    public EventoBean(){
        log.debug("Iniciando el objeto PersonaBean");
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializar(){
        //Inciamos las variables
        this.eventos = eventoService.listarEventos();
        log.debug("personas recuperadas en ManagedBean:" + this.eventos);
        this.eventoSeleccionado = new Evento();
    }
    
    public void editListener(RowEditEvent event){
        Evento evento = (Evento) event.getObject();
        eventoService.modificarEvento(evento);
    }
    
      public Evento getEventoSeleccionado() {
        return eventoSeleccionado;
    }

    public void setEventoSeleccionado(Evento eventoSeleccionado) {
        this.eventoSeleccionado = eventoSeleccionado;
    }

    public List<Evento> getEventos() {
        return eventos;
    }

    public void setEventos(List<Evento> eventos) {
        this.eventos = eventos;
    }
    
    public void agregarEvento(){
        
        this.eventoService.registrarEvento(eventoSeleccionado);
        this.eventos.add(eventoSeleccionado);
        this.eventoSeleccionado = null;
    }
    
    public void eliminarEvento(){
        this.eventoService.eliminarEvento(eventoSeleccionado);
        this.eventos.remove(this.eventoSeleccionado);
        this.eventoSeleccionado = null;
    }
    
    public void reiniciarEventoSeleccionado(){
        this.eventoSeleccionado = new Evento();
    }
    }
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Listado de Eventos</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:ajaxStatus style="width: 16px;height: 16px;" id="ajaxStatusPanel">
            <f:facet name="start">
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="ajaxloading.gif" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="complete">
                <h:outputText value="" />
            </f:facet>

        </p:ajaxStatus>

        <h:form id="eventosListForm">
            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
            <p:messages/>

            <p:dataTable id="eventosDataTable" value="#{eventoBean.eventos}" var="evento" editable="true" rowKey="#{evento.idEvento}" 
                         selection="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado}" selectionMode="single" >

                <f:facet name="header">
                    Listado de Eventos
                </f:facet>
                
                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <h:outputText value="#{evento.idEvento}" />
                </p:column>
                
                <p:column headerText="Id Admin Creador">
                    <h:outputText value="#{evento.idAdmin}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Nombre">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{evento.nombre}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{evento.nombre}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Género">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{evento.genero}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{evento.genero}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Descripción">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{evento.descripcion}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{evento.descripcion}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Cantidad de Boletos">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{evento.cantboletos}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText type="number" value="#{evento.cantboletos}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Lugar">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{evento.lugar}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{evento.lugar}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Fecha">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{evento.fecha}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{evento.fecha}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Precio por Ticket">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{evento.precioTicket}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText type="number" value="#{evento.precioTicket}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Subgénero">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{evento.subgenero}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{evento.subgenero}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Regresar" action="adminDash.xhtml" />
                    <p:spacer height="5px"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Agregar" actionListener="#{eventoBean.reiniciarEventoSeleccionado}"
                                     update=":dialogForm" oncomplete="PF('eventoDialog').show()" />
                </f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Opciones" style="width: 50px">
                    <p:rowEditor/>
                </p:column>

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{eventoBean.editListener}"/>

            </p:dataTable>
            
            <p:contextMenu for="eventosDataTable">
                <p:menuitem value="Eliminar" update="eventosListForm:eventosDataTable" icon="ui-icon-close" 
                            actionListener="#{eventoBean.eliminarEvento}" />
            </p:contextMenu>

        </h:form>

        <p:dialog id="eventoDlg" widgetVar="eventoDialog" header="Agregar Evento" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" 
            resizable="false" >
            <h:form id="dialogForm">
                <p:outputPanel id="eventoDetail" style="text-align: center">
                    <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="8" columnClasses="label, value" >
                        <h:outputText value="Nombre" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado.nombre}" />
                        
                        <h:outputText value="Genero" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado.genero}" />
                        
                        <h:outputText value="Descripción" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado.descripcion}" />
                        
                        <h:outputText value="Cantidad de Boletos" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado.cantboletos}" />
                        
                        <h:outputText value="Lugar" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado.lugar}" />
                        
                        <h:outputText value="Fecha" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado.fecha}"  />
                        
                        <h:outputText value="Precio por Ticket" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado.precioTicket}" />
                        
                        <h:outputText value="Subgénero" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{eventoBean.eventoSeleccionado.subgenero}" />
                        
                        
                        <f:facet name="footer" >
                            <p:commandButton value="Agregar" actionListener="#{eventoBean.agregarEvento}" 
                                             update="display,:eventosListForm:eventosDataTable" oncomplete="PF('eventoDialog').hide();" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
        

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**ERROR**

Estas son la primeras líneas o las mas importantes que me resultan importantes.

```
    Could not instantiate converter for type float: java.lang.NullPointerException|#]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

```
    Could not instantiate converter for type int: java.lang.NullPointerException|#]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Hola Mateo, bienvenido, el mensaje es claro, estás intentando usar variables que no fueron instanciadas, ninguna de ellas está en los códigos que subiste, puuede que estén en la clase **EventoService** o en **Evento** que no nos muestras, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y las agregues, (sin getters ni setters), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.